# Encryption during installation

Tags: encryption, lvm

I've been reading a lot about encrypting Ubuntu, but I'm really lost here because the more I read, people keep talking about *"full disk encryption"*, *"desktop encryption"* etc.

So when I installed **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** I checked the following 3 options.

1. Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu
2. Encrypt the new Ubuntu Installation for Security.
3. Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation.

And then I choose to write the extra space.

My questions are:

1. Is this a *Full Disk Encryption*? Everything is encrypted? or someone would be able to read any data?
2. If I plug another disk to the PC with e.g. Windows and boot with Windows and try to go and retrieve data from the Ubuntu hard drive.... is that possible?

The thing is that I need a secure full disk encryption because of my job. I'm a Lawyer and my computers have been robbed two times and sensitive information leaked, so I guess that I can't prevent another robbery but I can prevent data leak.

Comment: As I read what you've done, yes your data should be encrypted.  When you boot, before you recognize Ubuntu you should be asked something like "Attempting to descypt master key .. Enter passphrase for hd0.gpt2 (xxxxxxxxx)" without any identification as to what's on your system (no mention of Ubuntu or anything).  Your second part I find somewhat confusing, I can boot a 'live' system on my system, and have it `mount` my partition and as long as I enter my passphrase I can view my encrypted-ssd's data, if I enter a wrong passphrase - no I cannot.

Comment: fyi:  No encryption is 100% complete (if it was your system wouldn't be able to read it & boot from it), so in my example there is enough unencrypted to throw the "Attempting to decrypt master.." message, check key is valid & open drive-data. This of course includes clues, that tell someone 'hacking' the system for example that I'm using GNU/Linux, but not that I'm using Ubuntu.   Usually though people breaking in to steal data will look for clues (quick photograph) around where machine was situated that will allow break in rather than brute-force.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer guiverc. Thats the information that I was looking for. I  know that no encryption is 100% secure and that If they steal my laptop they can brute force my password. I've been reading a lot about "security" in the last couple of days. Password has no personal info, no work info, no words or numbers related to me. Its a long password..., random upper and lowercase letters, numbers and quite a few symbols, so by the time they access the drive the information will be useless. Besides I will start encrypting each document to add an extra protection layer ! Thanks mate !

Comment: Encryption is the use of clever mathematics to make the encrypted portion of the disk forever unreadable jibberish by anybody who lacks the key. It's not some kind of bypassable ultra-password. However, it is not perfect protection - your files are readable/deletable/hackable by an intruder *while you are logged in*. If you forget or lose the key, then your own files are unrecoverably gone forever. If an intruder encrypts your files with their key, then the files are gone forever. Encryption is just one step of healthy data security. Intrusion prevention and reliable backups are others.

Comment: @Entity look up the diceware method for passwords. These are best for ones you have to memorize.  Otherwise the use of a password manager like keepass is a near-necessity these days -- also lock it with a very strong diceware password.  pass + key file goes one step further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read what you've done, yes your data should be encrypted. When you boot, before you recognize Ubuntu you should be asked something like

```
Attempting to decrypt master key...
Enter passphrase for hd0,gpt2 (xxxxxxxxx)
```

without any identification as to what's on your system (no mention of Ubuntu or anything).

Your second question I find somewhat confusing, I can boot a 'live' system on my system, and have it `mount` my partition, and as long as I enter my correct passphrase I can view my encrypted-ssd's data, if I enter a wrong passphrase - no I cannot read anything from my ssd.

fyi: *No 'full-disk' encryption is 100% complete (if it was your system wouldn't be able to read it & boot from it), so in my example there is enough unencrypted to throw the "Attempting to decrypt master.." message, check key is valid & open drive-data. This of course includes clues, that tell someone 'hacking' the system for example that I'm probably using GNU/Linux, but not that I'm using Ubuntu. Usually though people breaking in to steal data will look for clues (quick photograph of where they stole it) around where machine was situated that will provide the clue that allows break in rather than brute-force.  ie. they defeat encryption because users are lazy and don't protect the needed passphrases writing it on a post-it note or something similar*

Comment: At least for EFI systems, Ubuntu can still be identified before entering a password and unlocking the volume that contains /root.  GRUB is not encrypted and the screen with the password prompt contains the Ubuntu logo to decrypt `sdx#`

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, I just looked (again) at a system, and didn't see any Ubuntu logo on my full-disk encrypted netbook (though that could be because what I looked at was a Lubuntu's [19.04] `calamares` install); however yes the EFI directory contains a Ubuntu directory, which is a huge clue